# .getjson is not working in MVc4

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I have seen many question on stack overflow related to json in MVC4 but could not understand the reason of error
Here is my client side jquery code

```
function Find() {
    var query = $('#bloodgroup').val();
    var text = "<ul>";
    if (query.length == 0)
        text += "<li>Please Select some blood group</li></ul>";
    if (text.length > 5) {
        $('#q').css('color', 'red');
        $('#q').html(text);
        return false;
    }
    $.getJSON("/home/SimpleSearchResult", { q: query })
        .done(function (data) {
            alert(data)
            $.each(data, function (i, item)
            {
            })
        })
        .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
            var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
            alert(err);
        });
}
```

And my controller action method is as follow

```
public JsonResult SimpleSearchResult()
    {
        string query = Request["query"];
        string q=Request["q"];
        var cx = new tempEntities();
        var list = cx.Users.Where(x => x.Blood.Contains(q)).Select(x => new { x.FullName,x.Blood,x.Cell,x.Email}).ToList();
        return this.Json(list,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

When I debug this code result from controller returns successfully but in jquery code .fail callback is executed. could not understand the reason of error.
Kindly help me in this regard

Comment: How are you calling `Find`?

Comment: onsubmit="find()". when a form is submitted. that has only one combo box to select blood group

Comment: If the request is being started from an `onsubmit` event and the `<form>` is continuing to submit as normal, the navigation by the form will force the Ajax request to be aborted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it is an option try using ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("SimpleSearchResult", "home")',
    type: 'post',
    cache: false,
    async: true,
    data: { q : query },
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data, function (i, item)
        {
        })
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this ?

```
$.getJSON("/home/SimpleSearchResult", {
    q: 'yourquerystringvaluehere'
}, (function (data) {
    alert(data)
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
        //do required action
    })
}))
    .fail(function (jqxhr, textStatus, error) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    alert(err);
});
```